# GetFileByServerRelativePath does not work and always returns file not found

Tags: c#, sharepoint

I was previously using the GetFileByServerRelativeUrl and it was working fine, but the characters # and % are not supported while they are supposed to be supported with GetFileByServerRelativePath, so I changed the code as per below but now it just doesn't work with any files???

```cs
public bool DownloadFile(string filepath, out string     Base64EncodedFile, out string errormessage)
        {
            Base64EncodedFile = string.Empty;
            errormessage = string.Empty;

            try
            {
                Uri filename = new Uri(filepath);                
                string serverrelative = filename.AbsolutePath;

                //This old method does not support # or % but works fine
                //Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File file = context.Web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl(serverrelative);

                // >> Replaced with this
                ResourcePath filePathDecoded = ResourcePath.FromDecodedUrl(serverrelative);
                Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File file = context.Web.GetFileByServerRelativePath(filePathDecoded);
                // << Replaced with this

                context.Load(file);
                ClientResult<System.IO.Stream> streamResult = file.OpenBinaryStream();
                context.ExecuteQuery();

                Base64EncodedFile = ConvertToBase64(streamResult.Value);            
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                errormessage = ex.Message;
                return false;
            }
        }

SharepointClient.SharepointClient newupload = new SharepointClient.SharepointClient("https://xxxxxxx.sharepoint.com/sites/xxxxxxxxx/", usernametext.Text, textpassword.Text);

            newupload.DownloadFile(Url.Text, out EncodedAbs, out errormessage);
```

If I use the old GetFileByServerRelativeUrl it works just fine... I tried everything but I cannot seem to get to work the GetFileByServerRelativePath ... I can't understand what I'm doing wrong???

Please help!!!

Comment: Is the variable filePath > 300 characters? i'm having the same issue, but only with long/deeply nested folder/filenames.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My test code for your reference.

```
using (ClientContext ctx = new ClientContext(targetSiteURL))
            {
                ctx.Credentials = onlineCredentials;

                string fileName = "FileWith#%.docx";
                var _File = ctx.Web.GetFileByServerRelativePath(ResourcePath.FromDecodedUrl($"/sites/lee/MyDoc/{fileName}"));
                ctx.Load(_File);
                ctx.ExecuteQuery();
                Console.Write(_File.ServerRelativeUrl);
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
```

[image]